# App crashes showing NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer in Android?

Tags: android, matcher, numberformatexception

In my app I'm returning the text that matches a given group of the regular expression using the match.group(int group) method where "match" is the Matcher object. But after running the app I'm getting a NumberFormatException. I tried using match.find() and match.matches() methods before using the match.group() method but then I'm getting an IllegalStateException and the app is crashing again.

This is my code:

```
public int getProgramNumberInt () {
    Matcher m = PROGRAM_NUMBER_INT_PATTERN.matcher(programNumber);
    return m.matches() ? Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)) : 0;
}
```

The crash happens at this line:

```
return m.matches() ? Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)) : 0;
```

Logcat:

```
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:412)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:382)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at com.example.Matcher.getProgramNumberInt(Starter.java:101)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at com.example.Matcher.results.ResultsActivity$Adapter.getPayoffView(ResultsActivity.java:127)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at com.example.Matcher.results.ResultsActivity$Adapter.getView(ResultsActivity.java:62)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1294)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-23 15:45:25.096: E/AndroidRuntime(16260):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Could you please let me know if there is any way to prevent the app from crashing and resolving this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Well, it looks like `m.group(1)` is returning an empty string. What *should* it contain?

Answer (score 0):

The method `m.group(1)` returns '' empty string. So the `parseInt()` method thows `NumberFormatException`.